# Hibernate: Parameter value did not match expected type?

Tags: hibernate

When I try to run:

```
List<MappingInstruction> result = emFactory.get()
          .createQuery("FROM " + MappingInstruction.class.getSimpleName() + " c where c.mapping = :mapping",
              MappingInstruction.class).setParameter("mapping", mappingInfo.getId()).getResultList();
```

I get:

> Service exception executing action "MappingAddAction",
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Parameter value [5118] did not
>   match expected type**
>   [com.vernuso.trust.server.domain.clientimport.MappingInfo (n/a)]

I debugged in Eclipse and `mappingInfo.getId()` does return 5118.

**Can someone please help me understand why it expects the type `MappingInfo` instead of `long`?**

I have two tables as shown in the image below. MappingInfo has One-To-Many relationship with MappingInstruction table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely:

```
List<MappingInstruction> result = emFactory.get()
          .createQuery("FROM " + MappingInstruction.class.getSimpleName() + " c where c.mapping = :mapping",
              MappingInstruction.class).setParameter("mapping", mappingInfo.getId()).getResultList();
```

You are fetching from **MappingInstruction** Entity. In the where condition, **c.mapping** is of type **MappingInfo**. Please check the datatype of mapping variable inside **MappingInstruction** class.

Because **c.mapping** is of type **MappingInfo**,but you are passing mappingInfo.getId() which is long, the ava.lang.**IllegalArgumentException** throws.

So, Correction is as follows:

```
List<MappingInstruction> result = emFactory.get()
              .createQuery("FROM " + MappingInstruction.class.getSimpleName() + " c where c.mapping = :mapping",
                  MappingInstruction.class).setParameter("mapping", mappingInfo).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I got too focused on the value in the table i.e. 5118.


Just a side question if you could answer: How can I remove an item from "result"? I tried result.remove(executionOrder); but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: result.remove(executionOrder) doesnt work!!! if you want to only delete from the list, but not from database too, you could copy the list to another list another list,then try to delete from that new list.

Comment: I want to remove the entry from the database. Since, I had fetched the result list from Db I was hoping that removing from this list would also reflect the changes in DB.